# Highlighting rspec in sublime text 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sublimetext2

The amount of DO END in my test files are getting confusing.

Is there a way to highlight the matching pairs of a DO or END in sublime text 2?

Bracket Highlighter doesn't have this functionality (although the developer is looking into it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed only to install the BracketHighlighter package (using the default repository in Package Control) and **restart Sublime** (important!). The answer by AGS is out of date.

Comment: Accepted this up to date answer for anyone who stumbles across this

Answer (score 6):

Edit

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/BracketHighlighter/bh_core.sublime-settings`

Add "RSpec" to the language list.

```
// Ruby conditional statements
    {
        "name": "ruby",
        "open": "(^\\s*\\b(?:if|case|until|unless|while|begin|class|module|def\\b\\s*[a-zA-Z_\\d]+)|do)\\b",
        "close": "\\b(end)\\b",
        "style": "default",
        "scope_exclude": ["string", "comment"],
        "plugin_library": "bh_modules.rubykeywords",
        "language_filter": "whitelist",
        "language_list": ["RSpec", "Ruby", "Ruby on Rails", "HTML (Rails)"],
        "enabled": true
    },
```

The result

[image: Result]

EDIT

Installing the Bracket Highliter "BH2" branch via package control:

Open

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings`

and add

```
"repositories":
[
    "https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/tree/BH2"
]
```

Then from the package control drop down menu: `Package Control: Upgrade Package` and select Bracket Highlighter.

Comment: The bh_core.sublime-settings file doesn't exist on my system. Does it need to be created? Bracket highlighter is installed via package manager

Comment: [You need to install the `BH2` branch.](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/tree/BH2).

Comment: See my edit for installing the `BH2` branch via package control.

Comment: Thanks. Installed ok, added "Rspec" and restarted, but still no do end highlighting. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have the [ST2 Rspec plugin](https://github.com/SublimeText/RSpec) installed?  If so, is your syntax set to `RSpec`?

Comment: @AGS What color theme are you using? My rspec is configured properly but I am not getting the proper `do` and `end` colors. I sense the theme may the culprit.